# error: anachronistic old-style base class initializer [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, error-handling

I have this constructor which give an error on compilation :-

```
Time::Time(short y,short m,short d,short h,short mi,short s):
        (*this).y(y);
        (*this).m(m);
        (*this).d(d);
        (*this).h(h);
        (*this).mi(mi);
        (*this).s(s);   {};
```

here is full error:-

```
Time.cpp: In constructor ‘Time::Time(short int, short int, short int, short int, short int, short int)’:
Time.cpp:22:2: error: anachronistic old-style base class initializer [-fpermissive]
  (*this).y(y);
  ^
Time.cpp:21:61: error: unnamed initializer for ‘Time’, which has no base classes
 Time::Time(short y,short m,short d,short h,short mi,short s):
                                                             ^
Time.cpp:22:9: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘.’ token
  (*this).y(y);
         ^
Time.cpp: At global scope:
Time.cpp:22:9: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘.’ token
Time.cpp:23:4: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘this’
  (*this).m(m);
    ^~~~
Time.cpp:23:4: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘this’
Time.cpp:24:4: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘this’
  (*this).d(d);
    ^~~~
Time.cpp:24:4: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘this’
Time.cpp:25:4: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘this’
  (*this).h(h);
    ^~~~
Time.cpp:25:4: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘this’
Time.cpp:26:4: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘this’
  (*this).mi(mi);
    ^~~~
Time.cpp:26:4: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘this’
Time.cpp:27:4: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘this’
  (*this).s(s);  {};
    ^~~~
Time.cpp:27:4: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘this’
Time.cpp:27:17: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘{’ token
  (*this).s(s);  {};
                 ^
```

As a noob I have no idea what is going on. On googling ,I only find one stackoverflow link which also doesn't help.

Comment: Try removing all the `(*this).`

Comment: Also replace all the semi-colons with normal commas

Comment: similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29422285/error-anachronistic-old-style-base-class-initializer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not allowed to use `this` to specify the class member you want to initialize in the constructor initializer list. Get rid of `this` entirely. It is not a matter of preference or style, it is just an error.

The error message about "old-style base class" is just a syntactic confusion: seeing nonsensical syntax in member initializer list the compiler gets confused.

Answer (score 3):

The way you have written it is not standard C++, hence the compiler diagnostic. Rewrite to the conventional syntax:

```
Time::Time(short y,short m,short d,short h,short mi,short s):
    y(y),
    m(m),
    // and so on, without a final comma
{
}
```

The compiler is able to disambiguate between a function parameter and a class member variable in this instance: `y(y)` initialises member `y` with parameter `y`.

Finally, are you sure you want `signed` types for time-like members?

Comment: I can’t compile with the `this->` syntax and the error message is even less helpful: [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/g/d2gSa2)

Comment: `this->` in constructor initializer list is simply illegal. Not "conventional".

Comment: @DanielH: Perhaps that is also anachronistic! (Actually, I've just tried it in the latest GCC and it is!) I've tinned it.

Answer (score 3):

When initialising using an initializer list, you need to seperate it by `,`, not `;`. And ditch the `this`

```
Time::Time(short _y,short _m,short _d,short _h,short _mi,short _s):
    y(_y),
    m(_m),
    d(_d),
    h(_h),
    mi(_mi),
    s(_s)
{
}
```

I would agree that it's not a great error message, in this case.

Comment: Your last edit is not needed, the scoping of `y(y)` is just fine.

Comment: Did it for clarity rather than for the compiler :)